# Optimization - PHP: Replacing the keys of an array with the value of another array if the keys match

Tags: php

I have created a function that takes two arguments, an array of users and an array of mapping attributes.

They look like this:

```
$users = [
   [
   "givenName" => "John",
   "surname" => "Doe"
   ]
]

$mappingAttributes = [
   "firstName" => "givenName",
   "lastName" => "surname"
]
```

I want to use $mappingAttributes as a map to replace the keys in $users with the keys in $mappingAttributes.

**Desired Output**

```
$users = [
   [
   "firstName" => "John",
   "lastName" => "Doe"
   ]
]
```

The function I created, which does the job, looks like this:

```
function mapAttributes(array $users, array $mappingAttributes): array
{
    $mappedUsers = [];
    foreach($users as $user) {
        foreach($user as $userAttributeKey => $userAttributeValue) {
            $newKey = array_search($userAttributeKey, $mappingAttributes);
            if($newKey != 0) {
                $user[$newKey] = $user[$userAttributeKey];
                unset($user[$userAttributeKey]);
            }
        }
        array_push($mappedUsers, $user);
    }
    return $mappedUsers;
}
```

This works, however, I feel like there must be a more optimal way to do this.

Comment: Sth. like this, maybe? https://3v4l.org/LbU9o If all your user items always have the same keys, and there are no extra keys that need to be preserved, then the "key translation" can happen once before the loop, instead of inside for each individual user item.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main thing is that you loop through all of the user fields, if instead you loop through the mapping fields, you only alter the ones that will change.

So....

```
 function mapAttributes(array $users, array $mappingAttributes): array
    {
        foreach($users as &$user) {
            foreach($mappingAttributes as $newKey => $oldKey) {
                if (array_key_exists($oldKey, $user))  {
                    $user[$newKey] = $user[$oldKey];
                    unset($user[$oldKey]);
                }
            }
        }
        return $users;
    }
```

this also updates the array in place (using `&$user`) rather than create a new array.